error - "Could not move temporary workspace to immutable location"
How common is the error in the stacktrace below?  It gets returned for my project with the cmd:
./gradlew clean --stacktrace
What is the most common root cause for this error?  Seems like the standard fix that I was using for this error was to delete node_modules and .gradle dirs.  But chatgpt just suggested that I update from gradle v8.6 to gradle v8.7 and now even those steps won't resolve the error below.  I'm guessing that there is some type of fundamental step or configuration that I need to adjust - for this as well as for my normal process - bc it doesn't seem like deleting those dirs should be expected as a standard step to get the app up and running, right?  I'm guessing that more experienced RN devs here have encountered this, know what the issue is and how to resolve.  Or at least how to avoid.
====
PS C:\CODE\myapp\android> ./gradlew clean --stacktrace
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-63de59f9-dbf2-4687-8fd9-99fca5ca246f) to immutable location (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Could not move temporary workspace (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-63de59f9-dbf2-4687-8fd9-99fca5ca246f) to immutable location (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


Try:


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-63de59f9-dbf2-4687-8fd9-99fca5ca246f) to immutable location (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)
at org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultDependenciesAccessors.generateAccessors(DefaultDependenciesAccessors.java:162)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.generateDependenciesAccessorsAndAssignPluginVersions(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:92)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:55)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.configureProjects(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:128)
at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.ensureProjectsConfigured(AbstractBuildState.java:131)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.AbstractCompositeParticipantBuildState.ensureChildBuildConfigured(AbstractCompositeParticipantBuildState.java:62)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.AbstractCompositeParticipantBuildState.getAvailableModules(AbstractCompositeParticipantBuildState.java:52)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.IncludedBuildDependencySubstitutionsBuilder.build(IncludedBuildDependencySubstitutionsBuilder.java:83)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.IncludedBuildDependencySubstitutionsBuilder.registerSubstitutionsFor(IncludedBuildDependencySubstitutionsBuilder.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildInclusionCoordinator.doRegisterSubstitutions(BuildInclusionCoordinator.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildInclusionCoordinator.registerGlobalLibrarySubstitutions(BuildInclusionCoordinator.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildInclusionCoordinator.registerSubstitutionsAvailableFor(BuildInclusionCoordinator.java:71)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:60)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$6(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransition$9(StateTransitionController.java:190)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransition(StateTransitionController.java:186)
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:173)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:36)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:36)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController$scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks$1.apply(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:112)
at org.gradle.configurationcache.VintageBuildTreeWorkController.scheduleAndRunRequestedTasks(VintageBuildTreeWorkController.kt:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:117)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:72)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-63de59f9-dbf2-4687-8fd9-99fca5ca246f) to immutable location (C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.unableToMoveBecause(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:329)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.lambda$executeMoveOrThrow$1(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:299)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOr(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:290)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOrThrow(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:298)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$moveTemporaryWorkspaceToImmutableLocation$6(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider$1.withTemporaryWorkspace(CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:119)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$moveTemporaryWorkspaceToImmutableLocation$7(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:247)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOr(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:290)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.moveTemporaryWorkspaceToImmutableLocation(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:241)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$executeInTemporaryWorkspace$3(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:220)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider$1.withTemporaryWorkspace(CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:119)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.executeInTemporaryWorkspace(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultDependenciesAccessors.executeWork(DefaultDependenciesAccessors.java:190)
at org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultDependenciesAccessors.writeDependenciesAccessors(DefaultDependenciesAccessors.java:167)
at org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.DefaultDependenciesAccessors.generateAccessors(DefaultDependenciesAccessors.java:153)
... 146 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-63de59f9-dbf2-4687-8fd9-99fca5ca246f -> C:\CODE\myapp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$moveAtomically$12(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:224)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.write(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:212)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.moveAtomically(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:223)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOr(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:273)
... 166 more

BUILD FAILED in 8s
PS C:\CODE\myapp\android>

My side its solved by closing same project opened on other tool except android studio, close metro bundler as well if you working on react native project.

@react-native/gradle-plugin Adding it as a devDependency first then try to run your app.
